# How to access a php var outside a while array, matching ID

Tags: php, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to understand a (probably) basic procedure but I think I'm missing something.
So I used a prepared statement to get some data from a mysql database:

```
<select>
  <?php
    $select_item_name = "select * from item order by item_name ASC";
    $run_item = mysqli_query($con, $select_item_name);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_item)){
      $item_id = $row['item_id'];
      $item_name = $row['item_name'];
      $item_price = $row['item_price'];
      $item_desc = $row['item_desc'];
      echo "<option value='$item_desc'>$item_name</option>";
      }
  ?> 
</select>
```

So when selecting a item name, I am able to access the selected item description, because I use the value assigned in option. But what if I want to access the selected item price or id? 
In the same page, in another php tag, outside the while, I want to access the  selected Item id and price, how do you do that?

```
<?php 
  echo "$item_id . "has a price of " . $item_price";
?>
```

If I do as shown in the code above, I get the last value in the database, and it does not change dinamically when selecting another item.

@Ryan Vincent
As you can see here:

```
echo "<option value='$item_desc'>$item_name</option>";
```

The while loop shows all db item names in the select dropdown.
Let's say I select item2 from the list.
I want to show in another point of the page, item2's id and item2's price. So when changing the option from the dropdown I want those values to dinamically change.
The issue here is the fact that I want to access those specific values from outside the while loop so I don't know how to call them.
Can you help me?

Comment: I guess you can access php variable on same page ,or you can set it in session ,using session_start() and $_SESSION[]

Comment: I need to access the var in a new <?php ?> tag, so it is the same page but not the same script.

Comment: You can try sessions then ! @thedude12

Comment: you can try `mysqli_fetch_all()`.

Comment: you could turn your db result set into a json dataset for the JS on teh page to interact with...

Comment: I edited my question to make it simpler, I still can't complete the task

Comment: @Ryan Vincent check question

Comment: If you want to show the item price details in a separate 'block' on the page then there are a few of ways of doing it. 1) save the row results in an array in the while loop. Use those details later on the page. Just use 'fetchAll' and store into an array.

Comment: Btw, I would use the `item_id` in the option value rather then 'item description'. It will be easier to select the selected row when it comes back from the client..

Comment: Ryan thanks for you feedback, I use id as value in my project, I explicitly used desc for the example and I know it is not really appropriate, By the way I tried fetchAll and understood it gives an associative array as a result but I still can't make it work (I'm a php beginner). Could you provide an example as answer? I'll make it top answer so anyone who has the same problem will get the solution. Thank you for your time.